# Problem with Wifi on startup, shows wifi connected but internet don't work?

Tags: wireless

I have to again switch off/on few times to make it work.
Always at start wifi shows that it is connected but internet don't work.
Even while writing this I manually off/on the wifi and it was showing Connected but I couldn't post the answer as Internet was not working, I again had to switch it off/on to make it work.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which version? It can be a bad hardware contact. We can only guess.

Comment: `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && chmod +x wireless-info && ./wireless-info && cat wireless-info.txt | nc termbin.com 9999`  Run in terminal and post termbin URL

Comment: Yes I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. I don't think it is bad hardware contact.I was using windows on it for many years and switched to Ubuntu just this week.It was running fine with fresh install but after I installed GSConnect and other software I noticed this problem.

Comment: https://termbin.com/u79lp

Comment: For now I have set keybindings for { rfkill unblock 0 } and { rfkill block 0 }

Comment: Can you change the wifi router to use channel 11?

Comment: I changed router channel to 11 but problem still persist.